# Separate Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word instance and Word app in machine

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

in my application i want to use microsoft word using

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application _wordApplication
= new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
this._wordApplication.Documents.Add();

object _readOnly;
    object _addToRecentFiles;
    object _confirmConversion;
    object _trueValue;
    object _falseValue;
    object _visible;
    object _nullObj;
object fileName = @"C:/FileName.doc";

var doc = _wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref _confirmConversion, ref _readOnly, ref _addToRecentFiles,
                    _oMissing, _oMissing, _oMissing, _oMissing, _oMissing, _oMissing, _oMissing, _visible, _oMissing,
                    _oMissing, _oMissing, _oMissing);
```

i want to separate between word application on my machine and word in my solution because if i modify the word application on machine with the following steps

> View > Read Mode

and close the word application 
then 
i open the word in my solution >> the word will open in

> Read Mode not Print layout mode

So my question is how to separate between Word application and word instance in my solution 
i want any change in my solution do not effect in microsoft office word in my machine and vice versa

Comment: Use the [edit] link below the question to include more code context. We need to see how `_wordApplication` is instantiated. Also, you can certainly set the *View* of the Word application after it has started, in your code. Did you try that?

Comment: @CindyMeister i changed the view by this code `_wordApplication.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = WdViewType.wdPrintView;`  but i want to work in my solution and does not reflect on the word app on my machine and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to how Word stores many of the settings values in the Registry (and others in the `Normal.dotm` template), under a single *user profile* key, it's not possible to choose or change what the Word application saves when it exits, whether the settings changes were made by a user or by code. This behavior is by design and cannot be configured differently.

The only way to keep a completely separate environment would be to run the "interop" version under a different user profile.

Barring that, to ensure that the "interop" environment runs with different settings from the end-user environment, the "interop" code needs take note of each setting of concern when it starts, change those settings to the ones required for itself and, when it ends, reset to the settings saved when the "interop" started.

There would be the possibility of starting a Word process in "Safe Mode", which would run Word using the installation defaults, but that would still mean creating settings when the instance starts. And, depending on what the code does, there may be other limitations/problems involved working under Safe Mode.

*Theoretically*, another approach would be to save the settings Registry key(s) - as I recall there are multiple keys where settings are stored, replace them with keys having the required settings, start the "interop" instance, then reverse the process when the "interop" ends. This is in essence essentially what the first approach does and would probably run into issues in an end-user environment without admin privileges, so I only mention it for the sake of completeness.